# unit testing - advice needed

Tags: java, maven-2, hudson

i have spring project that consists of a parent and few child projects.
the build is maven-based and the continous integration server is hudson.

i need to choose the way the unit tests will run.
currently, there are several good and also quite few garbage junit tests.
i preffer not to mess with the test packages of the child projects since it would be time-consuming, i am not familiar with all the junits and the last but not least: i'm lazy.

my questions are:

1. should i use maven-surefire-plugin and do a heavy cleanup in the test package?
2. is it any way to tell hudson (not in pom.xml of the project being built) to run specific unit tests and ignore others?
3. should I create some other build - (ant?) and use it for running unit tests on hudson?
4. are there any other options good options in the market i am not aware of?

any piece of advice would be appreciated.

aviad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. should i use maven-surefire-plugin
>      and do a heavy cleanup in the test
>      package?
> 2. is it any way to tell hudson (not in
>      pom.xml of the project being built)
>      to run specific unit tests and
>      ignore others?

If you just want to run unit tests in a single-module project, you can do

```
mvn test
```

That will run all [maven lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) up to `test`, including `compile` and `test-compile` (as you can see in [built-in lifecycle bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings), the [`surefire:test`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) goal is executed in phase `test`). Now if you want to restrict the unit tests that are executed, you can configure the [`surefire:test`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) plugin execution with the [`test`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) parameter:

```
mvn test -Dtest=Funky*Test
```

(This will execute all test classes that start with `Funky` and end with `Test`)

---

Unfortunately, the command line configuration is limited, if you want multiple includes and excludes you will have to do some XML configuration. I'd suggest to use a dedicated profile for hudson:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>hudson</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/TestA.java</include>
                            <include>**/Funky*Test.java</include>
                            <include>**/Test**.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- overrides above include -->
                            <exclude>**/TestButNotMe.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now you can let your hudson call maven like this:

```
mvn -Phudson test
```

Comment: Thanks! It was helpfull (sorry for not voting - my reputation is still < 15)

Comment: I belive there must be a whitespace between P and profile name in the command line statement.

Comment: @Ralph whitespace is not needed, but thanks to you I now know that it's possible to add a whitespace :-)

Comment: Ok, but I belive the profile should be the last argument, at least after the target (or is this only a convetion too)?

Comment: @Ralph yes, and a convention I don't share. My convention is `mvn maven_params goal goal_params` and profile is a maven parameter, not a goal parameter

Answer (score 3):

> 1) should i use maven-surefire-plugin and do a heavy cleanup in the test package?

yes

> 2) is it any way to tell hudson (not in pom.xml of the project being built) to run specific unit tests and ignore others?

I don't know any if you use JUnit. But you could check the "hidden" features of version 4.7, 4.6, 4.5... (there are many, you can found it in the release notes). If there is nothing what you need, then you could program it by yourselfe. (checking for a system property and skip the test).

> 3) should I create some other build - (ant?) and use it for running unit tests on hudson?

This would be the same like sprecifiying it in the pom. But in my personal opining mixing Ant and Maven is one of the uggliest thing you can do.

> 4) are there any other options good options in the market i am not aware of?

Have a look at [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html).

Comment: I took a look on testng ... looks promissing. do you have an idea how easily it integrates with spring? (failed to find an answer on this one)

Comment: @aviad JUnit (especialy 4.x) is easy integrated into Spring - you just need to add @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @ContextConfiguration("context.xml") to your test case, then you can inject beans in your test case. -- Anyway if you have more questions, then please create a new question instead of using comments. -- If you like my answer, feel free to vote for it.

Comment: +1 , @aviad: about testing in Spring read this chapter: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html There's a lot you can do!